# Why I get an error when adding __init__(self) method to Django rest framework viewset class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I Am keep getting a error when trying to build a Django API.

I have this class:

```
from uuid import UUID
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.http.request import HttpRequest
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from Instruments import serializers
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from Instruments.services import InstrumentsService
from Instruments.models import Instrument
from Instruments.serializers import InstrumentsSerializer


# Application views live here
class InstrumentViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # instruments = Instrument.objects.all()

    def __init__(self):
        # self.instrument_service = InstrumentsService()
        # self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
        super().__init__()

    def list(self, request: HttpRequest):

        try:
            self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
            serializer = InstrumentsSerializer(self.instruments, many=True)
            # data = self.instrument_service.get_instruments()
            data = serializer.data
            return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as exc:
            return JsonResponse(
                {"Status": f"Error: {exc}"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                safe=False,
            )
```

when the **init**() method is defining even if it is just doing `pass` the django server gives me this error when I send a request:

```
TypeError at /api/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'suffix'
```

If I remove or comment out the init() method it works.why??

Comment: why do you need the __init__?

Comment: to define some variables

Comment: Where do you need these variables ? In django,  **override __init__** is considered as wrong thing to do.  You can override the `list` or `create` or `update` ... Read [the doc here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) and if your not able to find a way, then you can override the **__init__** method.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that. But it is a good Python practice to define all you object variables in the init function. Otherwise where would you define them?  And th problem remain when  I override the init() function i get the error I mentioned. How can I make it work do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “got an unexpected keyword argument” exception is rather descriptive. What it means is your class instance (in this case, your ViewSet instance) was initialized with a keyword argument that you’re not handling. That can be fixed by doing the following in your **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # self.instrument_service = InstrumentsService()
    # self.instruments = Instrument.objects.all()
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

This is required because the super class (View) utilizes **kwargs when the instance is initialized.

For the record, this is not using Django as it was intended. Django was never meant for service layers and using the **init** method like this is counterproductive since a ViewSet takes a queryset variable. I would encourage you to read the documentation much more thoroughly before continuing with this project of yours.

Comment: Thanks. What documentation are you referring to please provide a link if possible. I did not encounter anywhere a discussion about using or not using services in the documentation of any of the modules or Django. It might be the case but I did not find anything. And not using service layers looks ugly and messy. What is the best practice for Django applications?

Comment: Actually I am looking at it now and I found more examples for using service layer than not. I see it is a best practice discussion but I cant find what the best practice actually is

Comment: Btw this worked, thanks. I didn't realize that there were arguments passed in the initialization, that fact that I dont handle its initialization confused me, but yeah of course it has more arguments

Comment: I suppose I was probably over-opinionated regarding service layers. I tend to agree with James Bennett [here](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2020/mar/16/no-service/) and I think I let it get the best of me. 

As far as documentation is concerned, I probably should have included it in the answer (still new to participating in SO… sorry), but the [django-rest-framework ViewSet documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) is the main piece I was referring to. Pay close attention to the ModelViewSet section as I think you’ll notice some glaring differences.